# Implementing a mutable sequence but with a fixed length in Python

Tags: python, collections, sequence

I want to implement an abstraction layer in Python for HW registers in an FPGA. This means,
that one can write to a key in the sequence, read from it, do the same for slices of said registers, but you cannot add or remove registers.

1. My problem is how to implement it
   elegantly in Python using `__getitem__()` and similar methods so it can behave properly.
2. I wonder, if I omit `__delitem__()` will something break?
3. What if I raise `NotImplemented` inside?
4. In the [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) there are `Sequence` and
   `MutableSequence` base abstract classes. Is it ok to inherit from `Sequence` and add
   `__setitem__()`, but omit `__delitem__()`?

I know, that probably Python will accept those and not complain, my questions are rather
abstract and I want to know what would be a good practice from the OOP design perspective.

Comment: From an OOP perspective, if you inherit from a base class which *does* provide a method that you don't want, then you *have* to override it yourself. You mentioned raising an exception which seems to be the right thing.

Comment: Also, I notice the link you provide it to python2 documentation. You should make sure you use python 3 now.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the Python version. It seems, that Python 3 has the same interface - [proper link here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). About raising an exception and inheritance, I still hesitate between implementing `Sequence` and extending it and `MutableSequence` and having `NotImplemented` raised. Semantically it seems the latter is best, since my sequence **is** mutable, but not entirely...

Comment: Ok, yes, since `MutableSequence` inherits from `Sequence` already, it is technically better to inherit from `Sequence` yourself and *add* the extra things you need.